# Why does it say that BuildTools pushes changes in GItHub instead of my account?

Tags: github

is it because i'm using vscode? i'm logged in to the correct account but it always says BuildTools instead of my account (zai-tm)

Answer (score 0):

If it "says" BuildTools by displaying "BuildTools" in your [`github.com/zai-tm`](https://github.com/zai-tm) repository commits, that means the `git config user.name` might be set to `BuildTools`

Make sure at least that those two commands return the right value

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

If not:

```
git config --global user.name  zai-tm
git config --global user.email <yourGitHUb Email>
```

Comment: yeah i feel stupid now. but thanks you. i didnt know how my name changed to BuildTools

Comment: @zai-tm No problem. Glad to help.